# how to get folder installdate from HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem
when i get HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ application to get its attribute
installLocation,it shows C:\Program Files\Alcoho 120, but I need to path formatC:\Program Files\Alcoho 120 to find the folder,and get its installdate

but i don't know how to convert from  C:\Program Files\Alcoho 120 to C:\Program Files\Alcoho 120
the error message shows warning C4129: 'A' : unrecognized character escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've pasted that path into your code like this:

```
char *path = "C:\Program Files\Alcoho 120";
```

If so, you need to double-up the backslashes since backslash is an escape character in C++:

```
char *path = "C:\\Program Files\\Alcoho 120"
```

You should not be hardcoding the path anyway, though; it may change depending on where it was installed. Your program should be looking in the registry instead. Hardcoding the *registry* path is fine since that won't change. Hardcoding the *file* path is not good.

(You will need to double-up the backslashes in the registry path if you put that in your code, of course.)

PS: Your question was really difficult to read; you might want to tidy it up.